# Dimension of polynomial in a polynomial ring.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

If $f(x)$ is ring of polynomials in $1$ variable $x$ over a field $F$ with $x^n=0$ for some (fixed) $n \in \Bbb{N}$, then what is the dimension of $f(x)$ over $F$

- a) $1$
- b) $n - 1$
- c) $n$
- d) Infinite

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: I think most would prefer if you did not put the entire question in the title, but rather the body of the post.

Comment: The answer depends on $n$ being the minimum exponent such that $x^n=0$.

Answer (score 1):

This "answer" is more of a guide to how to approach the question, and a kind of explanation of what the question means, rather than an actual answer. If the OP addresses the questions I've posed here, I'll add further detail.

$f(x)$ is a pretty unusual notation for this, but I'll go with it.

Step 1: Do you see why $f(x)$ is a vector space over $F$? How are addition and scalar multiplication defined?

Step 2: Can you think of a basis for $f(x)$ as a vector space? How would you show that the elements of your basis are linearly independent?

Step 3: How many elements does your basis have?

You can answer each of these questions by editing your question (with the "edit" link just beneath the question.